# Device Registration Id for Android and iOS for mobile web application using pyfcm

Tags: python, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

I am new to push notification. I am trying to use [pyfcm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfcm/) for sending push notifications. A few questions:

1. Registration_ids: I am not sure how to get the "registration_ids" for iOS and Android through pyfcm.
2. Also is it same as the instance id token?
3. Is it always same for a device or is it specific between an app and device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *1. Registration_ids: I am not sure how to get the "registration_ids" for iOS and Android through pyfcm.*

[Registration ID/Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials) can only be generated on your client app side (Android/iOS).

See how to setup an Android Client [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client), iOS Client [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client), and JavaScript Client [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client).

> *2. Also, is it same as the instance id token?*

AFAIK, this is also a term sometimes used for the Registration Token. Since it is from the [InstanceID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/) the Registration Token comes from.

> *3. Is it always same for a device or is it specific between an app and device?*

Each token is unique for each app instance (i.e. device). Referring from the Registration token docs I linked in #1:

> An ID generated by the FCM SDK for each client app instance. Required for single device and device group messaging. Note that registration tokens must be kept secret.